# PHP - using a namespace in another namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to use some files from another namespace inside one of my own namespaces, however it's not recognising the exceptions from the `Defuse\Crypto` namespace.

I've checked all the files, and everything is there stored perfectly in my directory. I can include the autoloader with no exceptions too.

What can I do to cleanly use both namespaces in the same file?

Here's my code:

```
namespace Defuse\Crypto;

$path = '/my/path/to/DefuseCrypto/autoloader';
require_once $path;

use \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
use \Defuse\Crypto\Exception as Ex;

namespace myNamespace;

class myClass
{
    static function encrypt_key($key)
    {
        try
        {
            $ciphertext = Crypto::encrypt($key, $privateKey);
            return $ciphertext;
        }
        catch (Ex\CryptoTestFailedException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Ex\CannotPerformOperationException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static function decrypt_key($key)
    {
        try
        {
            $decryptedKey = Crypto::decrypt($key, $privateKey);
            return $decryptedKey;
        }
        catch (Ex\InvalidCiphertextException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Ex\CryptoTestFailedException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Ex\CannotPerformOperationException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use namespaces in classes. But you start from root with leading \

Try this:

```
use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
use Defuse\Crypto\Exception as Ex;
```

After namespaces are included, you can use them. If you want to use a namespace often (more than 1 time), include namespaces in the top. Otherwise, you can use the full path at the place where you need.

Further, for maintainbility reasons use max. 1 namespace line.

Change your first line in:

```
namespace myNamespace;
```

And remove the second namespace line!

Comment: what do you mean? I don't have a namespace called `Namespace`

Answer (score 0):

Three options: either you specify the fully qualified (so absolute) namespace directly:

```
catch (\Defuse\Crypto\Exception\CryptoTestFailedException $ex)
```

Or you use a relative namespace inside the currently active namespace:

```
catch (Exception\CryptoTestFailedException $ex)
```

Or you have to declare the namespace under an alias for internal usage just as @HenriS. suggested above:

```
use Defuse\Crypto\Exception as Ex;
[...]
catch (Ex\CryptoTestFailedException $ex)
```

In general nothing speaks against using multiple namespaces in one file, that is common. But I agree with @HenriS. here that it is *not* a good practice to create a separate namespace for exceptions.

Comment: This is a library I'm using, I didn't make the exceptions

Comment: OK, then you should import the top level of the namespace inside your file. So place _your_ namespace at the top (you can only use one active namespace) and then use the `use` statement to import all namespaces from the library as aliases which you can then use inside your class. so like the third case in my answer with your own namespace on top.

Comment: "Still not working" has never helped anyone anywhere at any time to find the issue. _What does that mean? Be precise!_ What happens? Do you get an error message? Then tell us!

Comment: sorry. here you go `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Defuse\Crypto\Exception\CannotPerformOperationException' not found`

Comment: And where is that line? At the top of the file whilst importing the namespace to an alias or did you try the use the qualified namespace inside the files code? Please add your current code to your question, so that we know what you are talking about. I suggest you make a horizontal line at the bottom, add a remark about changes due to suggestions here and then post the current state of the code. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84980/discussion-between-mightyspaj3-and-arkascha).